# How to generate random positive and negative numbers in VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to generate random integers over the range (-5, 5) using VBA, something like 100+/- rnd 5.  I was wondering if some of you has more elegant way to do it. What I have so far is only "+"

```
randomRange= 100 + CInt(Rnd * 5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.

```
randomRange=100 + cint((Rnd()*((-1)^INT(rnd()*10))) * 5)
```

Where

- **(Rnd()*((-1)^INT(rnd()*10))) * 5**  is the part that generates number between -1 and 1.
- *5 gives a number between -5 and 5.

Thanks to [DRJ on Mr. Excel Forum](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/83786-negative-random-numbers.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Excel's `RANDBETWEEN` function like this:

```
randomRange= 100 + Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(-5, 5)
```

Comment: This is a very interesting approach, and very elegant.  However it only works in Excel, but many thanks for sharing this!

Comment: You're welcome. I noticed your question was only tagged VBA, but still assumed it was Excel. What context are you using it in?

Comment: Excel, but I do a lot of VBA elsewhere so I was curious to find out other ways.  Yours is so nice I am giving you the answer.

Comment: With a reference set to the Excel Object Library, you can do this with VBA from an application other than Excel: `Debug.Print Excel.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(-5, 5)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
randomRange = 100 + CInt(5 * (2 * Math.Rnd - 1))
```